# How do I change the way lists are presented in the terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, osx, ls

I'm new to working with the terminal and recently I have watched a few videos online, and customized it a little bit to suite my workflow (Color Schemes).

My issue is that some of the directories I have on the laptop are massive and when I want to display a list (`ls` / `ls -la` / `ls -a` commands for example), the list is set to a one column drop down.

How can I make it appear in more columns ? Think this will make searching for files/directories much easier.

An example of how it should look.

[image: An example of how it should look.]

Things I tried to do : Google'd it, tried to find a tutorial on YouTube and searched StackOverflow, even forked a dotfile repository to see if the list will change it's display with no success.

Comment: This is the output `ls` produces by default, unless some filenames are so long that there's only room for one column. `ls -l` prints lots of details about files, thus it never prints more than one file in a row.

Comment: @egmont this is not set by default on my machine for some reason. could you advise how to set.

Comment: Try the `-C` option. Also, check `man ls` to review particular options available for `ls` on your machine.